# Weird `:local` in `CSS` output file

Tags: webpack, keyframe, postcss, css-modules, css-loader

I simply declare a `key-frames`:

```
@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

But in `CSS` file that `Webpack` made for me I see:

```
animation: 1s infinite alternate :local(spinner)
```

What is `:local`???

I search and found some solutions but why it appear in css?

some of solution was, where I use the declared animation I must use `:global`:

```
:global .i-spinner4 {
    animation: 1s infinite alternate spinner;
  }
```

I used that solution I found, it became right but in `webpack -p` css version it dissapear completely, it means `PostCSS` parser in prod version ignore it completely...

How I can fix this???

this is my dev version `webpack` config:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const DistDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    SrcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            AppRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app'),
            PcssRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pcss')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: ['src/app/redux', 'node_modules'],
                include: SrcDir,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.pcss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: SrcDir,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true,
                                localIdentName: '[local]',
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                ident: 'postcss',
                                sourceMap: true,
                                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                                map: true,
                                plugins: () => ([
                                    require('postcss-partial-import')({
                                        prefix: "_",
                                        extension: ".pcss",
                                        glob: false,
                                        path: ['./src/pcss']
                                    }),
                                    require('postcss-nested-ancestors'),
                                    require('postcss-apply'),
                                    require('postcss-custom-properties'),
                                    require('postcss-nested'),
                                    require('postcss-cssnext')({
                                        features: {
                                            nesting: false
                                        },
                                        warnForDuplicates: false
                                    }),
                                    require('postcss-extend'),
                                    require('css-mqpacker')({
                                        sort: true
                                    }),
                                    require('autoprefixer')({
                                        browsers: [`last 15 versions`]
                                    })
                                ])
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 1024,
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    publicPath: '../font/',
                    outputPath: 'asset/font/'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: `asset/css/style.css`
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(`${DistDir}/asset`)
    ],
    entry: {
        "sd": `${SrcDir}/app/index.js`
    },
    externals: {
      config: JSON.stringify(require(SrcDir + '/config/config.dev.json'))
    },
    output: {
        path: DistDir,
        filename: "asset/js/[name].bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {inline: true},
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

And this my prod version `webpack`:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const DistDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    SrcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');

let q = [],
    cache = {};

function randomNaming(length,limit) {
    let result = '',
        chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_',
        fchars = 'abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_';

    do {
        if (q.length >= (52 * Math.pow(64, limit - 1)) && limit >= length) {
            return 'OutOfPossibility';
        } else if (q.length >= (52 * Math.pow(64, limit - 1)) && limit < length) {
            ++limit;
        }
        result = '';
        result += fchars[Math.floor(Math.random() * fchars.length)];
        for (let i = limit - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        }
    } while (q.includes(result));
    q.push(result);
    return result;
}

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            AppRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app'),
            PcssRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pcss')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: SrcDir,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.pcss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: SrcDir,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                modules: true,
                                getLocalIdent: (loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
                                    var randName = randomNaming(3,2);
                                    if (localName.match(/^i-/i)) {
                                        randName = `i-${randName}`;
                                    } else if (localName.match(/^i_/i)) {
                                        randName = `i_`;
                                    } else {
                                        randName = `${randName}`;
                                    }
                                    if (typeof cache[localName] == 'undefined') {
                                        cache[localName] = randName;
                                        return cache[localName];
                                    } else {
                                        return cache[localName];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                ident: 'postcss',
                                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                                plugins: () => ([
                                    require('postcss-partial-import')({
                                        prefix: "_",
                                        extension: ".pcss",
                                        glob: false,
                                        path: ['./src/pcss']
                                    }),
                                    require('postcss-nested-ancestors'),
                                    require('postcss-apply'),
                                    require('postcss-custom-properties'),
                                    require('postcss-nested'),
                                    require('postcss-cssnext')({
                                        features: {
                                            nesting: false
                                        },
                                        warnForDuplicates: false
                                    }),
                                    require('postcss-extend'),
                                    require('css-mqpacker')({
                                        sort: true
                                    }),
                                    require('autoprefixer')({
                                        browsers: [`last 15 versions`]
                                    })/*,
                                    require('postcss-csso')({
                                        comments: false
                                    })*/
                                ])
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 1024,
                    name: '[hash:base64:3].[ext]',
                    publicPath: '../font/',
                    outputPath: 'asset/font/'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: `asset/css/style.css`
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(`${DistDir}/asset`)
    ],
    entry: {
        "sd": `${SrcDir}/app/index.js`
    },
    externals: {
        config: JSON.stringify(require(SrcDir + '/config/config.prod.json'))
    },
    output: {
        path: DistDir,
        filename: "asset/js/[name].bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {inline: true},
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was made when I declare a `keyframes` without any hint to `css-loader` for `CSS Modules`, I must write like below:

```
@keyframes :local(spinner) {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Every `keyframes` must declare with `:local` when `Modules` are `true` in `css-loader`, then easily write your `class` with any property and its `animation` property. like below:

```
.my-class {
    animation: spinner 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use the name of the animation first ...

I was able to get rid of the failed build by simply using the name of the animation first as shown below

```
animation: spinner 1s infinite alternate
```

instead of => *animation: 1s spinner infinite alternate*

---

Another workaround is to not use the animation shorthand property. It causes the name of the animation to be **localised**, e.g:

```
.fadein {
  animation-duration: 300ms
  animation-name: fadein
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/141)

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this problem when using version 2.0.0 of `css-loader`.

It seemed to be a bug caused by one of their dependencies, as related in this issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/872

The problem was fixed in version 2.0.2, so just upgrading to 2.0.2 solved it for me.